# Recursive function to find sum of fractions which are factorials eg 1/0! + 1/1! + 1/2!... using C

Tags: c, math

Trying to find a way to find the sum of the fractions which is outputted from a factorial function in a recursive way. The code I have below only pulls the value at number input (n) instead of adding all the previous numbers first.

1. input of `5`
2. expected output: `2.7166666667`
3. actual output: `1.008333`

```
#include <stdio.h>

float fact(int n);

int main() {
    int n;
    float e = 1.0;

    printf("Enter length: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    e = e + (1.0 / fact(n));

    printf("\nThe value of 'e' is : %.10f\n", e);
    return 0;
}

float fact(int n) { 
    if (n == 1) 
       return 1;
    else
       return n * fact(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: `float e = 0; for (int i=0; i<=n; i++) e += 1.0 / fact(i);`

Comment: Must you do this recursively?  The iterative solution is much clearer.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately, I am aware that it is much easier to solve iteratively as Iłya has show above but the overall project is to demonstrate the difference between iterative and recursive and the use of functions

Comment: Ceallaigh, curious, why does code use `float` and not `double` variables yet uses `double` math as in `1.0/fact(n)`?

Comment: Agreed: *never* use `float` without a clear reason why you cannot use `double`, the natural floating point type in C. Old teaching material isn't a good reason. You don't use `short` instead of `int` just because the range is small, unless you have constraints which can't be met.

Comment: Welcome! Please post the input, the expected output, and the actual output as text *in the question*. May I also suggest you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: To sum the series I would sum a 'running term' which in each iteration divides by *n*. There is no need for a factorial function.

Comment: Are you trying to compute the Euler's number? `e = e + (1.0/fact(n));` does *not* compute a sum with `n` ranging over some set of integers. You may want to use a loop of some sort for that.

Comment: To write a recursive function, you need figure out four things. 1) What information does the function need. 2) When does the function stop. 3) What calculations are needed before and after the recursive call. 4) What should the function return. With the `fact` function, you've answered all those questions. 1) It just needs `n` where `n` decreases as the recursion depth increases. 2) It stops when `n` is 1. 3) The calculation before the recursive call is `n-1` and after it's "multiply the returned value by `n`". 4) Either return 1 when `n` is 1, or return the product.

Comment: And the key to answering the first question is in [Weather Vane's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74647539/recursive-function-to-find-sum-of-fractions-which-are-factorials-eg-1-0-1-1#comment131760286_74647539). If you implement that idea with an iterative loop, it will be much easier to see what information the recursive function needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only calculating one term of the series `(1/fact(n))`, and adding it to 1.0. What you need to do is loop over all values of n, from 1..n, and adding it to a result. Doing this iteratively is easier and more intuitive than using recursion.

Just like an iterative function, you need to keep track of the result, which can be accessed inside the function body. This is mostly done by passing the result as a parameter to the function.

When making a recursive function, you always need to think of the base case. In this case, the base case is when the number is equal to 0. This is because we need to find all terms from 1/n! + 1/(n-1)! ... 1/0!.

A recursive implementation for this problem may look something like this:

```
double series(int n, double result) {
    if(n == 0) {
        return result + 1;
    }

    result += (1 / fact(n));

    return series(n-1, result);
}
```

Note that we need the '+ 1' in the base case, because 1/0! = 1.

As you can see, as n gets increasingly large, the result gets closer to Euler's number 'e'.